# How to interpret a plot of promp result?

Tags: r, pca, prcomp

My PCA result using prcomp() function is summarised and plot as followings. How to interpret the plot results? It shows in some online article that the points present the amount of variance attributed to the different principal components. However, the value seems not matching with any of the statistics, e.g., standard deviation, the proportion of variance, or cumulative proportion.

```
> summary(data_pca)
```

[image]

```
> plot(data_pca,type="lines")
```

[image]

Comment: Since this is not a coding question, this seems more appropriate as a question over at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). On top of that, you can find **a lot** of information on the interpretation of these (commonly called) **scree plots**. Please take some time researching, and if still unclear I would suggest posting a question over at CV.

Comment: Calculate the squared standard deviations and compare with the plot. Also, read `help("screeplot")`.

Comment: @Roland, thanks both. I understood now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the hint from @Roland and @Maurits. Here, the variance is exactly the square of standard deviation.